# Saving a complex model to DB via Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Given the following code, I am trying to save the complex object Institution to the db. If I take out references to address the base institution saves correctly but with the Address added in I get a foreign key error and nothing saves. What is the correct way to save a complex class?

```
   Institution inst = new Institution();
   inst.Name = "Institution Name";
   Address address = new Address();
   address.Street1 = "1234 west main";      
   address.City = "Gotham";
   address.State = "WI";
   address.PostalCode = "55555";

   List<Address> addresses = new List<Address>();
   addresses.Add(address);
   inst.Addresses = addresses;              
   db.Institutions.Add(inst);
   db.SaveChanges();
```

The institution class:

```
 public class Institution
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Institution Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

The address class:

```
 public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Street")]
    public string Street1 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(2)]
    public string State { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Zip")]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public virtual Institution Institution { get; set; }
    public virtual AddressType AddressType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You'd have to first save the primary entity to the db to generate it's ID if its auto increment. Then assign it to the address object of yours. That's why it's suggested you create seperate repository classes for every object you have.

Comment: That's what I was expecting. I just wasn't sure if there was some way built in.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the one-to-many relationship (and the foreign key definition) by overriding the OnModelCreating in your DbContext. Something similar to the following should work:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Institution>().HasMany<Address>(i => i.Addresses)
        .WithRequired(i => i.Institution).HasForeignKey(i => i.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define Institution with the a constructor.

```
public class Institution
{
    public Institution()
    {
            Addresses = new Addresses<Student>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Institution Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can write your add code like the following

```
  Institution inst = new Institution();
   inst.Name = "Institution Name";
   Address address = new Address();
   address.Street1 = "1234 west main";      
   address.City = "Gotham";
   address.State = "WI";
   address.PostalCode = "55555";

   inst.Addresses.Add(addresses);              
   db.Institutions.Add(inst);
   db.SaveChanges();
```